# Impedance matching between 93 ohm and 50 ohm

Tags: impedance-matching

I have a detector of an unusual impedance of 93 ohm connecting to a digitizer of 50 ohm through a coaxial cable of 50 ohm. Unfortunately I can not change the impedance setting of my digitizer.

According to the reflection formula, I would expect 30% of a signal to be reflected, resulting in a decrease in magnitude. Can I calibrate the output on my digitizer by multiplying a factor (1.42 in my case) to get the unreflected signal?

If that is not possible, how can I mitigate the effect?

Comment: If you know it, what is the expected highest frequency of your signal being detected ? Is it the low MHz, high MHz, GHz etc ?

Comment: also what is the expected typical signal frequency of your signal being detected that needs to be digitalised ?

Comment: @citizen the typical and the highest frequency will be in the order of MHz, ranging from 1 MHz to 100 MHz. I am new to the device so I am not sure are they considered as "low" or  "high" frequency.

Comment: Is the coaxial cable long ? What length is it ?

Comment: 1-100MHz could be covered with a transformer (of 4:3, 11:8 or 15:11 turns ratio), but may be a bit of a pain to wind, or hard (impossible?) to find commercially; and may need additional circuitry to deal with biasing, termination, etc.  If you can afford the losses, the min-loss attenuator in the answer is easiest.

Comment: @Voltage Spike♦  An "exponential line" is an impedance matcher. There is a line between the 2 systems. So inserting this "matcher" adapt the two systems. And moreover, it is a very large wideband "matcher". So, no error to mitigate. It is thus an "answer".

Comment: @citizen I have coaxial cables of different lengths--ranging from 20cm to 1m.

Answer (score 3):

> *how can I mitigate the effect?*

[This calculator on my basic webpage](http://stades.co.uk/Impedance%20TX/Zmatch%20basic.html) can match the 93 Ω on the detector to the 50 Ω of the coax: -

[image]

The gain figure (\$A_V\$) is going from left (50 Ω) to right (93 Ω) but, this can easily be recalculated to give a calibration number from right to left (0.320002).

Of course, if the coax is shorter than about one tenth the wavelength of your highest frequency (100 MHz) then there's probably little reason to perform any matching. 100 MHz has a wavelength of 3 metres in free-space. Along a cable it'll be about 2 metres so, if the coax is shorter than 20 cm, I probably wouldn't bother matching.

Comment: Can I know what \$A_V\$ means in this case? Is it the ratio of \$V_{in}\$/\$V_{out}\$? I looked at your website, and it mentioned attenuation of "5.33dB". But shouldn't attenuation be a negative value?

Comment: An attenuation of 5.33 dB is a gain of -5.33 dB. Av in the example in my question is the circuit voltage gain from the top of R2 to the output at the top of RL. I think you meant 5.633 dB didn't you?